# Correct use of 'mayhap'

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct use of "mayhap"?

Can you use it interchangeably with 'perhaps' or 'maybe'?

Could I use it in an informal letter at the CPE writing part or is this an archaic form?

Edit: How about 'mayhaps'?

Comment: "Mayhap" is archaic and should not be used, unless quoting an archaic source, or imitating an archaic style of English.

Comment: [*Mayhap*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mayhap): "adverb - an archaic word for perhaps". I have never heard this used (AmE).

Comment: We would only use _mayhap_ in preference to the modern _maybe_ or _perhaps_ in a humorous way. There is no "plural" form, despite the seeming similarity to _perhap**s**._ Informally, use _maybe_. In a more formal setting, _perhaps_ may be preferable.

Comment: I would not say that *mayhap* is archaic.  It is unusual but it is heard in current usage.

Comment: It's the kind of word you might hear in the deep South or Appalachia. http://www.dancingonmountaintops.com/mountaintalk.htm

Comment: The OED says it is used in British regional dialects - but irritatingly it doesn't say which ones. I've never heard it used and I like to consider myself someone who is attentive to regionalisms. I suspect it is a word like "somewhen" which was used in the 19th century and is occasionally still heard. I had a colleague who used it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

"Mayhap" is technically interchangeable, but it's archaic. An old British television series called *[Catweazle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catweazle)* focuses on a magician from hundreds of years ago who has accidentally travelled through time; he says "mayhap".

> **mayhap** *adverb (archaic)*
>
> perhaps; possibly

*Source: Oxford Dictionaries*

Answer (score 1):

Mayhaps is technically correct.  So, too, are mayhappen, may happe, and mappen, all circa 1530-1580.  They're all archaic in the continental USA, but you may still encounter usage of mayhap or mayhaps in the deep mountains of Appalachia, and mayhap is still in regular use in the UK.

Comment: It's not in regular use in the UK.

Comment: Oh!  Okay.  ^-^  Thank you for letting me know. 